# What's the right way to create modules on Typescript for NPM and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

The problem is that it's not quite understandable how to create the NPM-module on Typescript.
Theoretically, two ways are possible:

- compiled
- uncompiled

Ideally I need the second variant , but now I have problems even with the first one.

I've done test repository ( with the description of how to run the system ), where I've posted an unsuccessful experience i creating the module.

https://github.com/khusamov/temp-ts-modules

I'd be glad if somebody would help us to solve the problem.